# How to check two HashMap are identical in Rust?

Tags: rust, hashmap, language-lawyer

I have two `HashMap`s ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8e42ca1d97d460a90010a358a89839d)):

```rust
let mut m1: HashMap<u8, usize, _> = HashMap::new();
m1.insert(1, 100);
m1.insert(2, 200);

let mut m2: HashMap<u8, usize, _> = HashMap::new();
m2.insert(2, 200);
m2.insert(1, 100);
```

How can I check if the two maps `m1` and `m2` are identical?

By "identical", I mean **all** of the following conditions are satisfied.

- Type of keys is same.
- Type of values is same.
- Two maps have exactly the same key set. Insertion order shall not matter.
- Two maps have exactly the same value for every key (i.e. `m1.get(k) == m2.get(k)` for every existing key `k`).

As far as I tested, just `m1 == m2` works. However, it this behavior guaranteed? I want a some sort of guarantee (thus I added `#language-lawyer` tag).

I've already read [the official documentation of HashMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html).

Also, what about `HashSet` and `Vec`? (I've also read their documentation.)

Comment: Looking at the way `PartialEq` is implemented for `HashMap` using `==` garanties what you want. It iterates every entries of the map and check if the other map has it, and if the values are equal.
[source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#1281-1287)

Comment: pretty sure it's the same for `HashSet` and `Vec` (`HashSet<T>` is basically `HashMap<T, ()>`)

Comment: so Vec calls `eq` on the underlying slice, which just iterate trough the slice and check if all values are equals: [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/cmp.rs.html#68-74) (there is other implementation if T is bitwise comparable, so it can just call `memcmp`), for Set it iterates through the keys and check if the other set has it: [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/set.rs.html#994-1000)

Comment: @Bamontan Thank you. So, as far as you know, isn't there any guarantee at language design level? I mean, in the future version of Rust, there is non-zero possibility the implementation (i.e. rustc) may optimize somehow to break the current comparison rule if there is no guarantee... Anyway, could you please post your comments as an answer? It was very helpful.

Comment: Regression are rare, almost inexistant. Whatever is on stable will probably never break, even more on common public APIs like those. I don't know if those behavior are graved in stone, but I can't see Rust make such a big change on something stable used so widely.

Comment: The main question is... what could the the alternative semantic? What else can make sense for comparing `HashMap`s, other then "key sets are equal, values at each key are equal"?

Comment: @Cerberus Comparing all of the fields of internal structure is one example. It is meaningful and possible (default PartialEq behavior), and may be even useful for limited users (e.g. developer of HashMap itself).

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the source of the std libraries you can find the implementation of `PartialEq` for those different collections:

- `HashMap` iterate over all key/value pair and check if the other map has a corresponding entry for that key, and then check if those value are equal: [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#1281-1287).
- `HashSet` iterate of the keys and check if the other set contains that key: [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/set.rs.html#994-1000).
- `Vec` actually call `eq` on the underlying slice, which either iterate across every values and compare them: [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/cmp.rs.html#68-74) or does a bitwise comparaison if the type allows it by calling `memcmp`: [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/cmp.rs.html#82-92).

I don't know if there is any kind of garanties that this behavior will never change, but being stables, widely use APIs, I don't see them change, ever.